# DAX selecting and displaying the max value of all selected records

Tags: powerbi, dax

**Problem**

I'm trying to calculate and display the maximum value of all selected rows alongside their actual values in a table in Power BI. When I try to do this with the measure `MaxSelectedSales = MAXX(ALLSELECTED(FactSales), FactSales[Value])`, the maximum value ends up being repeated, like this:

[image: Duplicated maximum]

If I add additional dimensions to the output, even more rows appear.

[image: Even more duplicates]

What I want to see is just the selected rows in the fact table, without the blank values. (i.e., only four rows would be displayed for SaleId 1 through 4).

Does anyone know how I can achieve my goal with the data model shown below?

**Details**

I've configured the following model.

[image: Power BI Data Model]

The `DimMarket` and `DimSubMarket` tables have two rows each, you can see their names above. The `FactSales` table looks like this:

| SaleId | MarketId | SubMarketId | Value | IsCurrent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 | true |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 50 | true |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | 60 | true |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 140 | true |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 30 | false |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 20 | false |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 90 | false |
| 8 | 2 | 2 | 200 | false |

In the table output, I've filtered `FactSales` to only include rows where `IsCurrent = true` by setting a visual level filter.

Answer (score 1):

Your max value (the measure) is a scalar value (a single value only). If you put a scalar value in a table with the other records, the value just get repeated. In general mixing scalar values and records (tables) does not really bring any benefit.

Measures like yours can be better displayed in a KPI or Multi KPI visual (normally with the year, that you get the max value per year).

If you just want to display the max value of selected rows (for example a filter in your table), use this measure:

```
Max Value = MAX(FactSales[Value])
```

This way all filter which are applied are considered in the measures calculation.

Here is a sample:

[image]

[image]

Comment: While I would normally agree with you, my requirements here are slightly different. What I’m trying to do with the max value is use it as input to a normalization measure ((Val - MIN) / (MAX - MIN). The issue comes when I try to use the MAX or MIN value in that calculation and display the result in a table. The rows all get repeated.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to my problem, but I'm slightly concerned with query performance. Although, on my current dataset, things seem to perform fairly well.

```
MaxSelectedSales = 
MAXX(
    FILTER(
        SELECTCOLUMNS(
            ALLSELECTED(FactSales),
            "id", FactSales[SaleId],
            "max", MAXX(ALLSELECTED(FactSales), FactSales[Value])
        ),
        [id] = MAX(FactSales[SaleId])
    ),
    [max]
)
```

If I understand this correctly, for every row in the output, this measure will calculate the maximum value across all selected `FactSales` rows, set it to a column named `max` and then filter the table so that only the current `FactSales[SaleId]` is selected. The performance hit comes from the fact that MAX needs to be executed for every row in the output and a full table scan would be done when that occurs.

<sub>*Posted on behalf of the question asker*</sub>